# CipherOutputStream creating 0 byte file

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to write an encrypted file using CipherOutputStream ,

PFB the code for serializing

```
public class SerializeDemo implements Serializable{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7128734972070518012L;

    private static SerializeDemo INSTANCE = null;

    private ArrayList <SerializeItem> item;
    public static void serialize() {
       INSTANCE = new SerializeDemo();

       ArrayList < SerializeItem > list = new ArrayList < SerializeItem > ();

       SerializeItem item = new SerializeItem();

       item.setV1("DD");
       item.setV2("D");
       list.add(item);

       INSTANCE.setItem(list);
       try {
           Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
           c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKeyPair().getPublic());

           CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\abc"), c);
           ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(cos);
           os.writeObject(INSTANCE);
           os.flush();
           os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }

        System.out.println("Serialized");
    }
}
```

PFB my SerializeItem  class definition

```
public class SerializeItem implements Serializable{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 850426811900126363L;

    private String V1 = null;

    private String V2 = null;

//getter setters for the bean file
}
```

If i add more than 2 String member variables in this class serialization stops and i am getting a 0 byte file. Kindly suggest

Comment: It is impossible to get a zero length file with this code even without writing an object, and indeed even without the `CipherOutputStream`, unless there was an exception. What was it? NB The point of the static `INSTANCE` escapes me.

Comment: There is no error while running the code and if i give only 2 fields then i do get a non zero length file.Static instance is for implementation of singleton pattern

Comment: There are only two fields in the code you posted. Are we to understand that haven't posted the non-working version?

Comment: I have posted the working bean , but if add lets say private String V3 = null; and try to encrypt the code we will get a 0 byte file

Comment: Hard to believe. Impossible actually. Look again to see whether there was an exception, and whether you're really running the code you think you're running.

Comment: I am using public key to encrypt , and no i am not getting any exception while running the code , is it because the data is more than the length of my public key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA is not a block cipher, and won't work as you're expecting with `CipherOutputStream`. The `close` method on `CipherOutputStream` is masking an `IllegalBlockSizeException` which is raised because your data is longer than the block size (keysize / 8 - padding).

You will see the exception if you call `c.doFinal()` before the close.